# Google's colab does not seem to show the icon shapes within widgets.Play (...)

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Google's colab, the Play widget does not show the infilled shapes. If you type the code below, you'll see the play button outlines faintly (shows better in the dark mode) but the play button icons such as single step and triangle (play) don't show up. Thanks for any feedback.

```
play = widgets.Play(
    value=50,
    min=0,
    max=100,
    step=1,
    description="Press play",
    disabled=False
)
slider = widgets.IntSlider()
widgets.jslink((play, 'value'), (slider, 'value'))
widgets.HBox([play, slider])
```

Answer (score 3):

Play widget uses FontAwesome to render the icons. Google Colab doesn't seem to include that.

You need to somehow include FontAwesome's CSS stylesheet, for example from https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css. Colab shows output in separate iframes, which means this has to be repeated for each output cell (that contains icons).

What worked for me (in Python 3 kernel) is to add `from IPython.display import HTML` in my imports and then following line as first in each input cell that shows Play:

```py
display(HTML('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>'))
```

Comment: Hi - this really worked - thank you so much! I used your solution successfully in the context of an automata-theory animation + exploration package I have written, and it is easy for me to incorporate it within the animation functions.